# Change date formate in drupal admin tables (log, content listing, edit pages, etc)

Tags: datetime, users

I've looked everywhere but can't find out how to change the date format in the admin/content/ table and the recent log table.

Current it is displayed as '09/05/2014 - 00:18'' but I just wanted to make it YYYY-mm-dd - hh:mm'

What's the best way to make this happen?

[image]

Comment: Install [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) and adjust the views to your taste. I'm not sure if it will replace the recent log table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `/admin/config/regional/date-time` you can change the way dates are shown. This applies to the whole site though.

Comment: thanks I actually thought that I tried that but after your post I tried again and it worked! I think that I might have just edited: admin/config/regional/settings